# Pandas count distinct days in each month an ID occurs

Tags: python, pandas

Considering this DataFrame:

[image: DataFrame]

Is there a way to count how many unique days each ID appeared in each 'WeekNumber' ?

I've managed to do so with SQL but would like to achieve the goal in a more elegant way and to a bigger scale(Not only on specific months and week numbers)

My SQL output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
(df.groupby('WeekNumber')['ID'].nunique())
```

If you need extra information, you can use `agg`:

```
df.groupby('WeekNumber')['ID'].agg(['min','max','count','nunique'])
```

Comment: I believe this will count how many unique id's were in each week number, not my desired result.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you need. You probably can get there after by creating the 'WeekAndMonth' column (as in your SQL result), and then using ```pd.crosstab```, :https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Comment: Which WeekAndMonth column are you referring to ?

Comment: in your SQL output you have 'Week_1_May', 'Week_2_May', etc..

Comment: But those columns are my desired output ... I Wand to Understand how to create those.

Comment: Yes it's just more work than I was expecting. I will try and help tomorrow morning :)